# Is this possible to broadcast the message from client side to server side in signal R?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

My Run function is in client side. I want to display a real-time alert in my notification bar. I want to inform my hub class on server side about this function, in order to do something like this.

```
HubProxy.Invoke("Functionname", parameter1, Parameter2)
```

In my Hub Class, i write the following code :

```
private hubConnection = New HubConnection("")
private MyHub As IHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub")
```

I dont know to pass my function from client to server.

My Project is Desktop Application Based.

Answer (score 0):

**Server part:**

```
public class YourHub: Hub
{
    public void SendMessageFromClient(string paramOne, string paramTwo)
    {
        // Invokes a message on all connected clients 
        Clients.All.messageFromServer(new ParameterClass() {ParameterOne = paramOne, ParameterTwo= paramTwo} ;
    }
}
```

Details about how to make your server part you will find here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server

**Client part**

```
//create connection
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("yourURL");
IHubProxy yourHub= hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("YourHub");
// Add eventhandler
stockTickerHubProxy.On<ParameterClass>("MessageFromServer", paramObj=> Console.WriteLine("Info from server. ParamOne:{0} ParamTwo {1}", paramObj.ParameterOne , paramObj.ParameterTwo ));
// Start connection
await hubConnection.Start();
```

How ParameterClass looks like:

```
public class ParameterClass{
  public string ParameterOne {get; set;}
  public string ParameterTwo {get; set;}
}
```

Details about client:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client